# Does anyone know how we can change the loss function in DNNClassifier tensorflow premade estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I want to use a separate loss function in the DNNClassifier as the data is highly imbalanced i want to use 
tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits as the loss function but i guess i need to build a new estimator for it?
Is it possible to change the loss function in the existing pre baked DNNClassifier by tensorflow Estimator API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the classifier's optimizer and the activation function in the hidden layers, but I don't think you can define a custom loss function.

Since your input data is "highly imbalanced," you can set custom weights by assigning your weights to the constructor's `weight_column` argument. The documentation is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier#__init__).

Comment: Hey Matthew, thanks for your answer, i was trying to figure out how we can added weights as a new column per instance/row of the data or just a tensor constant defined as - tf.constant([0.9,0.1])
When supplied with the constant as defined above to the estimator, it doesnt really work as it looks for a new feature as weights in the data! 
 Can you give me some sample of how the weights should be like ? Thanks a lot!